# Is there a way to list files on host from within kubernetes pod?

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes

Hello I'm trying to create a containerized file-system management tool.

Is there a way I can list files on my host nodes file-system from within my pod/container?

Comment: A design goal of Docker is that you can't: the container filesystem is isolated from the host's.  You also tagged this [kubernetes], and there not only is that isolation there but you also can't easily control _which_ host you're running on.  This doesn't seem like a good technology match.

Comment: The app would probably require a DeamonSet to manage a k8s cluster

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you have a `volumeMount` pointing to the `hostPath:` volume, although I can't say with high certainty it will do the right thing with regard to other bind mounts on the host:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: looker
    volumeMounts:
    - name: host
      mountPath: /host-fs

  volumes:
  - name: host
    hostPath:
      path: /
```